# Suppress scientifc notation from decimal.Decimal to String

Tags: python-3.x, decimal

I have decimal.Decimal objects that need to be turned into strings, without losing precision, while losing their scientific notation.

```
Decimal('1E-8')  -------->   '0.00000001'

Decimal('8769.97900000')  ---------> '8769.979'
```

I've been using string formatting,

```
"%.12f" % num
```

But sometimes I lose precision.

What is the best way to do this?  The below is very ugly, and fails for the last item.

```py
from decimal import Decimal

def descientize(startStr):
    stripped = startStr.strip('0')
    spot = len(stripped) - stripped.rfind('.') -1 if stripped.rfind('.') != -1 else 0
    if 'e' in stripped.lower():
        dec, exp = stripped.upper().split('E')
        spot = -int(exp) + int(len(dec) - dec.rfind('.') -1 if dec.rfind('.') != -1 else 0)
    ret = f"%.{spot}f".strip('0') % Decimal(stripped)
    return ret


NUMS = ['8769.97900000', '1e-08', '14', '15.35567760000', '12.04', '1.083458374643534e-08', '1.083458374643534e80']

for num in NUMS:
    print(f'{num} ----> {descientize(num)}')
```

Comment: Do you mean you have numbers with more than 12 characters after the decimal point?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with `format(my_decimal, 'f')`.

Comment: Are you starting with a `Decimal` instance, or with a `str` object?

Comment: Mark: Starting with decimal.  Also never used the `format` reserved keyword, interesting!

Answer (score 1):

You can format any `Decimal` instance in non-scientific notation using the plain `'f'` format. This will always preserve all of the digits of the original `Decimal` object, and will not round to a particular fixed number of digits:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> format(Decimal("3.210e20"), "f")
'321000000000000000000'
>>> format(Decimal("3.210e-20"), "f")
'0.00000000000000000003210'
>>> format(Decimal("-1.083458374643534314159e10"), "f")
'-10834583746.43534314159'
```

In your particular case, it looks as though you also want to remove trailing zeros. You can do that with a call to the [`Decimal.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize) method:

```
>>> x = Decimal('123.560000')
>>> format(x, "f")
'123.560000'
>>> format(x.normalize(), "f")
'123.56'
```

If you're working with a reasonably recent Python, you might also use f-strings for this:

```
>>> f"Value of x is {x.normalize():f}"
'Value of x is 123.56'
```

However, you should be aware that the `normalize` method can change the value if the context precision is not large enough to represent the normalized result. For example:

```
>>> from decimal import getcontext
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal('123.56789000').normalize()
Decimal('123.568')
```

To avoid this problem, you may want to strip trailing zeros manually instead. Here's a short function:

```
def format_and_normalize(dec):
    s = format(dec, "f")
    if "." in s:
        s = s.rstrip("0").rstrip(".")
    return s
```

And an example of its use (still with the current context precision of `6` significant digits):

```
>>> format_and_normalize(Decimal('123.56789000'))
'123.56789'
```

Note that old-style (`%f`) formatting on a `Decimal` instance always converts that `Decimal` to `float` first, possibly changing the value being formatted. One of the major benefits of the `format`-based formatting is that it's extensible to non-built-in types.